# Netbeans IDE 13 won't create a new project on Mac

Tags: netbeans-13

I am running java 8 on my Mac, but when I try to create a new project it gives me this error saying it cannot enable Maven. I never had this problem on windows.

Answer (score 0):

> The Apache NetBeans 13 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially
> support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17.

Source: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html

Therefore try to upgrade your JDK.